# How to access a relationship through another relationship

Tags: laravel

I am working on a survey system and I have a problem accessing one relationship through another.
I have these models and these relationships

Post

- id
- survey_id

```php
public function survey()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
}
```

Surveys

- id
- survey_type_id

```php
public function surveyOptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Survey_options::class);
}
    
public function surveyType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey_type::class);
}
    
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Survey_types

- id

```php
public function surveyOptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Survey_options::class);
}
```

Survey_options

- id
- survey_type_id

```php
public function values()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Option_value::class);
}
```

options_values

- survey_options_id
- survey_id

```php
public function surveyOptions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey_options::class);
}
```

Survey_Survey_options (pivot)

- survey_id
- survey_options_id

I need to do a query with eadger loading to bring me all the posts with survey, surveyOptions, withCount comments y options_values of each surveyOptions. Something like this:

```
$post->survey->surveyOptions->options_values_count
```

I have managed to create this query that works for me everything except fetching the option_values count from each SurveyOption. How can I do it?

```
$posts = Post::with([
            'survey' => function ($query) {
                $query->withCount('totalSurveys');
            },
            'survey.surveyOptions',
            'image',
            'categories'
          ])
          ->withCount('comments')
          ->get();
```

Comment: What's wrong with `withCount()`?

Comment: maybe I'm doing it wrong, but as I've tried it I can't do: withCount('survey.surveyOptions.values')